# Macports and Fink - co-exist OK?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, macports, fink

I have a Mac with OS 10.6.8 and with Fink currently installed.

I would like install Macports and use that as well.

Is there any reason I should not do this ? What risks are involved ?

Answer (score 0):

I have both installed and I wouldn't recommend it. Since they are both designed to be 'self-contained', when they install something new, they only check under their own directory (and not your computer $PATH) for any dependent packages that are needed. If either of them don't find the dependent package in their own directory, they will install the dependent package there. This means you end up with a lot of duplicated installations which clog up your memory.